# I restart node red but the user is still loged in

Tags: authentication, node-red

I  enabled user authentication on Node Red. but when I restart the service the user is still logged in

I have done some searches. there is some suggestions around changing the machine key every time the service restarts.

does anyone have any suggestions about what exactly should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://nodered.org/docs/security#token-expiration) on securing Node-RED the authentication tokens generated last for 7 days.

You can change this by editing the `settings.js` file

> The expiration time can be customised by setting the sessionExpiryTime
> property of the adminAuth setting. This defines, in seconds, how long
> a token is valid for. For example, to set the tokens to expire after 1
> day:
>
> ```
> adminAuth: {
>     sessionExpiryTime: 86400,
>     ...
> }
> ```

EDIT:

The session tokens on the backend are (when using the default storage plugin) stored in a file called `.sessions.json` in the userDir (as logged on startup). If you want to log out all users on a restart then you will need to delete this file before starting Node-RED.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But I want the user to be logged out right after I restart the service. so he or she have to log in again

Comment: Edit the question to more clearly explain the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I want the authorization tokens to be deleted every time I start the Node-RED

Comment: As I said please edit the original question, to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve and why